# How to fix this error? (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: chat not found

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to set up a telegram bot. I entered all the data but then this error comes out.

I tried to reload.

I don’t know which fragment to insert.Probably here.

Inserting the code is what happened

```
errro in getChatMember { Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: chat not found
    at request.then.resp (/app/node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js:280:15)
    at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
  code: 'ETELEGRAM',
  response:
   IncomingMessage {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: true,
        endEmitted: true,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        paused: false,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0m,
        readingMore: 3mtrue,
        decoder: null2m,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [Array],
        close: [Array],
        data: [Function],
        error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'api.telegram.org',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'api.telegram.org',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: -1,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'api.telegram.org',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'api.telegram.org',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: -1,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     httpVersionMajor: 1,
     httpVersionMinor: 1,
     httpVersion: '1.1',
     complete: true,
     headers:
      { server: 'nginx/1.16.1',
        date: 'Sat, 31 Aug 2019 19:43:05 GMT',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'content-length': '73',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'access-control-expose-headers': 'Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server,Connection' },
     rawHeaders:
      [ 'Server',
        'nginx/1.16.1',
        'Date',
        'Sat, 31 Aug 2019 19:43:05 GMT',
        'Content-Type',
        'application/json',
        'Content-Length',
        '73',
        'Connection',
        'keep-alive',
        'Strict-Transport-Security',
        'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        '*',
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
        'Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server,Connection' ],
     trailers: {},
     rawTrailers: [],
     aborted: false,
     upgrade: false,
     url: '',
     method: null,
     statusCode: 400,
     statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
     client:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'api.telegram.org',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'api.telegram.org',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: -1,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     _consuming: false,
     _dumped: false,
     req:
      ClientRequest {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [TLSSocket],
        connection: [TLSSocket],
        _header:
         'POST /bot935567004:AAHzn_nFK3ROZZ16TTtoENflnjuD-luYtPc/getChatMember HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: api.telegram.org\r\ncontent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\ncontent-length: 40\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Agent],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path:
         '/bot935567004:AAHzn_nFK3ROZZ16TTtoENflnjuD-luYtPc/getChatMember',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Circular],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     request:
      Request {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        simple: false,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        forever: true,
        readable: true,
        writable: true,
        explicitMethod: true,
        _qs: [Querystring],
        _auth: [Auth],
        _oauth: [OAuth],
        _multipart: [Multipart],
        _redirect: [Redirect],
        _tunnel: [Tunnel],
        _rp_resolve: [Function],
        _rp_reject: [Function],
        _rp_promise: [Promise],
        _rp_callbackOrig: undefined,
        callback: [Function],
        _rp_options: [Object],
        headers: [Object],
        setHeader: [Function],
        hasHeader: [Function],
        getHeader: [Function],
        removeHeader: [Function],
        localAddress: undefined,
        pool: [Object],
        dests: [],
        __isRequestRequest: true,
        _callback: [Function: RP$callback],
        uri: [Url],
        proxy: null,
        tunnel: true,
        setHost: true,
        originalCookieHeader: undefined,
        _disableCookies: true,
        _jar: undefined,
        port: 443,
        host: 'api.telegram.org',
        body: 'chat_id=-1001457333935&user_id=749901319',
        path:
         '/bot935567004:AAHzn_nFK3ROZZ16TTtoENflnjuD-luYtPc/getChatMember',
        httpModule: [Object],
        agentClass: [Function],
        agentOptions: [Object],
        agent: [Agent],
        _started: true,
        href:
         'https://api.telegram.org/bot935567004:AAHzn_nFK3ROZZ16TTtoENflnjuD-luYtPc/getChatMember',
        req: [ClientRequest],
        ntick: true,
        response: [Circular],
        originalHost: 'api.telegram.org',
        originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
        responseContent: [Circular],
        _destdata: true,
        _ended: true,
        _callbackCalled: true },
     toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
     caseless: Caseless { dict: [Object] },
     body:
      { ok: false,
        error_code: 400,
        description: 'Bad Request: chat not found' } } }
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `status` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at TelegramBot.bot.on (/app/app.js:201:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
^C
```

(node:4) **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:**

> Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: chat not found
>       at request.then.resp (/app/node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js:280:15)
>       at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
>       at _drainQueueStep (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
>       at _drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
>       at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
>   (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Dear please mention the code which case this error.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Bot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch promise errors by adding catch to send message , so please add catch block in all send message function and check which one case that error

```
bot.sendMessage(message.chat.id, text, params).catch(e => console.log("in 1", e) );
```

Adding catch in promise chain will prevent logging warn message but it will print an error message `400 Bad Request: chat not found` ;

I expect that the error could be here please log `schema.ref` and make sure that is a valid chat id.

```
schema.ref      =       Number(message.text.split("/start ")[1]);
bot.sendMessage(Number(message.text.split("/start ")[1]), ` Вы пригласили <a href="tg://user?id=${message.from.id}">пользователя</a>, вам начислено <b>${settings.ppr}₽</b>`, {
            parse_mode: "HTML"
        });
```

Full example to track the issue :

```
bot.on("message", async (message) => {
    let ban = await Ban.findOne({ id: message.from.id });
    if(ban) return;

    message.send = (text, params , method ) => bot.sendMessage(message.chat.id, text, params).catch(e=> console.log("errro in " + method , e) ) ;

    await bot.getMe().catch(e=> console.log("errro in getMe" , e) );

    $menu = [];
    keyboards.main.map((x) => $menu.push(x));

    if(admins.find((x) => x === message.from.id)) $menu.push(["⚡️ Админка"])

    User.findOne({ id: message.from.id }).then(async ($user) => {
        if($user) return;

        let schema = {
            id: message.from.id,
            balance: 0,
            ref: 0,
            epr: 0,
            eps: 0,
            epv: 0,
            menu: "",
            adminmenu: "",
            prfUser: "",
            prp: {},
            regDate: `${new Date().getDate()}.${new Date().getMonth() + 1}.${new Date().getFullYear()}`,
            verify: false
        }

        if(Number(message.text.split("/start ")[1])) {
            schema.ref      =       Number(message.text.split("/start ")[1]);
            bot.sendMessage(Number(message.text.split("/start ")[1]), ` Вы пригласили <a href="tg://user?id=${message.from.id}">пользователя</a>, вам начислено <b>${settings.ppr}₽</b>`, {
                parse_mode: "HTML"
            }).catch(e => console.log("error in  Вы пригласили ", e ));

            let ref = await User.findOne({ id: Number(message.text.split("/start ")[1]) });
            if(ref) {
                await ref.inc("balance", settings.ppr);
                message.send(`Благодарю, что вы воспользовались приглашением <a href="tg://user?id=${ref.id}">пользователя!</a>` , {} , "Благодарю");
            }
        }

        if(typeof(message.text.split("/start ")[1]) === "string") {
            let link = await Ref.findOne({ name: message.text.split("/start ")[1] });

            if(link) {
                if(!link.refs.find((x) => x === message.from.id)) {
                    link.refs.push(message.from.id);
                    await link.save();
                }
            }
        }

        let user = new User(schema);
        await user.save();

        return message.send(`Выберите действие. ⤵️`, {
            reply_markup: {
                keyboard: $menu,
                resize_keyboard: true
            }
        },"Выберите");
    });

    message.user = await User.findOne({ id: message.from.id });

    let { status } = await bot.getChatMember(-1001457333935, message.from.id).catch(e=> console.log("errro in getChatMember" , e) );;
    if(status === 'left') return message.send(`➕ *Для того, чтобы* начать/продолжить работу с ботом, *вы должны быть подписанным* на канал https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAFbdJq9JTae6gCB9ag`, 
    {
        parse_mode: 'Markdown',
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{ text: '➕ Подписаться', url: 'https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAFbdJq9JTae6gCB9ag' }]
            ]
        }
    }, "➕ *Для того, ");
})
```

Comment: I could not understand what I need to do now. Yes, I'm not sure what the problem is in this place.

Comment: I do not think that the problem is in schema.ref

Comment: Please add this code `.catch(e => console.log("in 1", e) );` after each `bot.sendMessage` function like I mentioned in my answer, also please change `in 1` each time with unique string to know in which call you get that error, also please print `schema.ref` after this line `schema.ref      =       Number(message.text.split("/start ")[1]);` to check if this valid id or not

Comment: No, I don’t know. It just shows an error in the logs.

Comment: So please run your app in request debug mode by this command `NODE_DEBUG=request node app.js` . this will print all requests from your app to other servers so it will print which request print that exception, and inspect request body and response.

Comment: I changed the code in the question. That's what came out of that request that you told me

Comment: Please check my answer I have added the full code, please replace your code with mine and run it normally , `node app.js` then till me what is the output

Comment: Inserting the code is what happened. Changed the code in question

Comment: so the problem is `await bot.getChatMember(-1001457333935 .... )` Please make sure that the `chat_id` is valid

Comment: and how do i replace it? I do not know